# ansible extract value from group_vars/all

Tags: ansible

I have following data structure in ansible group_vars/all:

***group_vars/some_group.yml***

```
my_group_var:
      para_1:
            type: aaaa
            limit: bbbb
      para_2:
            type: cccc
            limit: dddd
```

How do I read values? Below is working code:

```
set_fact:
    new_var_1: my_group_var['para_1']['type']
    new_var_2: my_group_var['para_1']['limit']
    new_var_3: my_group_var['para_2']['type']
    new_var_4: my_group_var['para_2']['limit']
```

But I want to do something like below:

```
set_fact:
    set new_var1 to new_var4(just like above)'{{ item }}'
with_items:
  - my_group_var
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    my_group_var:
          para_1:
                type: aaaa
                limit: bbbb
          para_2:
                type: cccc
                limit: dddd
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        "new_var_{{ item.0 * 2     }}": "{{ my_group_var[item.1]['type'] }}"
        "new_var_{{ item.0 * 2 + 1 }}": "{{ my_group_var[item.1]['limit'] }}"
      with_indexed_items: "{{ my_group_var.keys() }}"
    - debug:
        var: new_var_{{ item }}
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{ (my_group_var.keys() | count) * 2 - 1 }}
```